# Setup my website on Azure VM

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, azure

I have an azure vm(windows server 2012), that I installed IIS on. I went to default website and added a new "application" and pointed it to my website code.

I can now see my website on the box via localhost. However I have no clue how to setup my domain to link to my website.

I am using namecheap as my domain provider.

Answer (score 1):

Your VM should have a public IP configured, if not then you would need to add one. You would also need to open up the inbound port (80 for http or 443 for https) on the Azure Network Security Group (if using v2 Vm's) or cloud service (if using v1).

Once that is done you should be able to resolve the site by IP address or the DNS name that Azure provides with the IP. You can then add an A record or a CNAME with your DNS provider to point your custom URL to this VM.

Comment: I think I added a static ip address by running some powershell commands(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/) but I am not sure where to open up the ports. V2 confused me as there is even less documentation on it so I am using the classic modal.

Comment: @chobo2 if you are using the classic model then you need to create enbpoints to allow traffic in, see here - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-setup-endpoints/ however I would really advise using the ARM model.